# Como puedo cambiar el texto por defecto que tiene la tabla TextView de JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, ingenieria-del-software

me gustaria cambiar el texto que sale por defecto en la tabla TextView de JavaFX pero no logro encontrar informacion relacionada para hacer el cambio, aparece siempre como **No content in table** pero quisiera personalizar eso.

Coloco imagen para que vean a que me refiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho el apoyo con estos detalles ya que soy bastante nuevo el desarrollo de interfaces con JavaFX, me imagino que se podria cambiar con `css` pero no se como referenciar hasta dar con el label o lo que sea que contenga el texto por defecto.

Comment: Me parece que era con Nombredetabla.setPlaceholder(new Text("sin contenido"));

Comment: Pero como haria si estoy untilizando una hoja de FXML ? como se haria desde ahi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 forma desde Fxml puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
 <TableView>
        <placeholder>
            <Label text="sin contenido"/>
        </placeholder>
 </TableView>
```

2 forma desde la clase Controller

```
nombreDeTabala.setPlaceholder (new Text ("sin contenido"));
```

Comment: Genial! muchas gracias amigo por tu ayuda, la primera opcion desde el FXML me funciono.

Comment: si te sirvió la respuesta, puedes calificarla como útil marcando ✓,saludos